# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null

Tags: jquery, angular, owl-carousel

I am using owlCarousel with angular 9 to show video. When it load return error `Cannot read property '3' of null`.

Here my html page for load OwlCarousel

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
    <a class="owl-video" href="{{data.imageUrl}}"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

typescript file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
       nav:true,
       items:1,
       autoWidth: true,
       video:true
     })
   });
 }
```

[image]

I'd be grateful for some help.

Comment: Please check in the debugger what array owlcarousel is accessing index 3 of, and what its contents are.

Comment: I would suggest using a library that supports angular. Using jquery with Angular does not make sense. And it will just complicate things.

Comment: There's `ngx-owl-carousel-o` for example. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o

Answer (score 0):

It look to me that, your carousel is getting initialised before it is available. For this you can use `*ngIf` to a property, when the property is truthy it will initialized.

```
<div *ngIf="somePropToBeTruthy" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jai for reply. I have try `<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-demo" *ngIf="data.imageUrl">`. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use carousel in angular like this instead of using jquery use angular's feature

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
<ng-template carouselSlide *ngFor="let data of sliderImages">
    <div class="slider-item">
        <img [src]="data.image" alt="data.image">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: true,
    autoplay: true,
    rtl: true,
    dots: false,
    navSpeed: 700,
    items: 1,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
    },
    navText: ['', ''],
    nav: true,
    autoHeight:true
};


 sliderImages = [
    {
       'image':'abc.png'
    }, {
       'image':'abc1.png'
    }]
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume jquery is properly integrated. Then, You should put the code inside `ngAfterViewInit` as below (ngAfterViewInit is the replacement of document's ready event),

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
       nav:true,
       items:1,
       autoWidth: true,
       video:true
     })
  
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is causing the issue?